# Is it the case that that $E(X_i) = 0 \implies \sum_{i=1}^n E|X_i| < \infty$?

Tags: real-analysis, probability, probability-theory

Is it the case that that $E(X_i) = 0 \implies \sum_{i=1}^n E|X_i| < \infty$? If so, what's the proof? Here $X_1, X_2, ...$ are random variables.

I considered Jensen's inequality, i.e. $E|X_i|\geq |E(X_i)|$ but that doesn't help. Also, I "know" it's supposed to be true but I couldn't find a proof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is true because $\mathsf{E}|X_i|$ is finite for each $1\le i\le n$ (otherwise, either $\mathsf{E}X_i=\pm\infty$ or $\mathsf{E}X_i$ doesn't exist).

Comment: Thank you for answer. I understand that if $E|X_i|$ is finite then the sum is finite as well. But could you be a little more explicit why $EX_i < \infty \implies E|X_i| < \infty$. I see what you write in parenthesis but this is not totally clear to me (sorry if obvious).

Comment: $\mathsf{E}X_i=0$ is possible only if $\mathsf{E}|X_i|<\infty$.